# Unhandled exception at 0x74E733AB (ucrtbase.dll) in OpenClaw.exe

Tags: c++, github, visual-studio-2017, open-source, sdl-2

I wanted to tinker this open source remake of the famous Claw.

Visit https://github.com/pjasicek/OpenClaw

Before I start with how I've cloned this game and tried to build it, I'm new to the open source community. I did the following things.

- I cloned the repository.
- Opened the project using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition and I changed the Configuration to **Release** and platform to **Win32**.
- I then built the **libwap** solution without any errors.
- Then I used **CMake 3.11.0** to generate the required files for the Box2D solution and then generated it and then the Box2D build was a success.
- I built the **Midiproc** manually and finally, I tried building the entire solution.
- It threw a **MSVCR120D.dll** missing error and I copied all the .dlls from the game's release folder https://github.com/pjasicek/OpenClaw/releases

Now the game runs just fine when I launch it from the File explorer, but when I try to **launch it from Visual Studio 2017**, it throws the following error.
Check out this image:

[image: Exception thrown]

How do I run the game from Visual Studio? Have I misconfigured the Visual Studio?

If you need any more details on what I did, please let me know.

[EDIT] I want to configure Visual Studio to be able to run the release and modify the source code so I can tinker it and try to understand how the game works internally.

Comment: ***It threw a MSVCR120D.dll missing error and I copied all the .dlls from the game's release folder*** This practice will likely cause you a serious problem. It's not safe to have more than 1 CRT unless the CRTs are isolated. Also you should not have a debug CRT in a release application. My advice is to recompile everything with your compiler (including all dependencies).

Comment: What is a CRT? and how do I isolate the CRTs? Can you be a bit more detailed on this? I'm new to this.

Comment: The easiest solution is to rebuild everything from the same compiler. Don't mix Visual Studio 2013 binaries (.dlls and executables) with Visual Studio 2017 binaries.

Comment: `MSVCR120D.dll` is a debug dll used in the Visual Studio 2013 runtime for debug applications. `ucrtbase.dll` is a release dll used in the Visual Studio 2017 runtime. Visual Studio 2017 is compatible with 2015 but not with 2013 (or any other version of VS) also Debug and Release are not compatible (you should not mix the two).

Comment: From the description I suppose you have wrong current working directory when launching it from IDE.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, I'll try to recompile all the solutions.

Comment: @keltar How do I configure the VS 2017 to use the change the working directory?

Comment: Its in the debugger settings of your target.

Comment: Okay, I've tried changing the working directory to the required folder and I still cannot run from the Visual Studio. @drescherjm

Can anyone please clone the repository and try to run it from the Visual Studio and let me know if you've made it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned the repository again and did a clean compilation of all the solutions. Turns out there was a problem when I copied/overwritten all dlls from the release build. Now, the game builds and executes fine.

Thanks for the help.